# Mysql - Count element in month group by day

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table with he following fields:

```
-id---start_date(datetime)---end_date(datetime)-
-1---02/11/13 4:00---02/11/13 5:00-
-2---02/12/13 4:00---02/12/13 5:00-
-3---02/11/13 5:00---02/11/13 6:00-
-4---03/11/13 4:00---03/11/13 5:00-
-5---02/11/13 3:00---02/14/13 3:00-
```

I want to count how many records there are every day in a range of days, starting from a start_date and ending in another end_date.
Eg selecting between 02/10/13 and 03/10/13:

```
-count---day(datetime)-
-3---02/11/13-
-2---02/12/13-
-1---02/13/13-
-1---02/14/14-
```

---

Thanks!
And if i want add a field in main table with the frequency of every records?
eg:
frequency
0: one single time;
1: every day;
7: every week;
etc...

```
 -id---start_date(datetime)---end_date(datetime)---frequency-
-1---02/11/13 4:00---02/11/13 5:00---7-
-2---02/12/13 4:00---02/12/13 5:00---0-
-3---02/11/13 5:00---02/11/13 6:00---0-
-4---03/11/13 4:00---03/11/13 5:00---0-
-5---02/11/13 3:00---02/14/13 3:00---0-
```

result:

```
-count---day(datetime)-
-3---02/11/13-
-2---02/12/13-
-1---02/13/13-
-1---02/14/14-
-1---02/18/14-
-1---02/25/14-
-1---03/04/14-
```

Comment: Have you tried any queries?

Comment: ^ also what is structure of your table? (especially which data type holds your dates)

Comment: I can count records of one day selecting 2 datetime, but i don't know how to reply this for a range of days

Comment: I presume these are mm/dd/yy format dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making some assumptions on the format of your data and the tables:-

```
SELECT aDate, COUNT(SomeDateTable.id)
FROM
(
    SELECT DATE_ADD("2013-02-10", INTERVAL (Hundreds.i * 100 + Tens.i * 10 + Units.i) DAY) AS aDate
    FROM
    (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) Units,
    (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) Tens,
    (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) Hundreds
    WHERE DATE_ADD("2013-02-10", INTERVAL (Hundreds.i * 100 + Tens.i * 10 + Units.i) DAY) <= "2013-03-10"
) sub1
INNER JOIN SomeDateTable
ON sub1.aDate BETWEEN DATE(SomeDateTable.start_date) AND DATE(SomeDateTable.end_date)
GROUP BY aDate;
```

This will cope with date ranges of up to 1000 days

SQL fiddle for it here:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/103b7/1

Comment: Thanks!<br>
And if i want add a field in main table with the frequency of every records?<br>
eg:<br>
frequency<br> 
0: one single time;<br>
1: every day;<br>
7: every week;<br>
etc...

Comment: Not quite sure how you want the frequency to reflect in the counts.

Comment: Main Question edited with example

Comment: If I understand what you mean (I think you mean that for the range 11/02/2013 to 11/02/2013 is repeated every week after that), I think it will be a nightmare to do in pure sql.

Comment: yes, i think so too. i can try to do all of this with php increasing queries

Comment: It could be done in SQL to an extent by joining the row against a table / sub query of numbers (similar to how my suggestion above works to fill in the days within a date range). Problem is the range would need to cope with the number of days / weeks / etc, that could be added. So if it were a daily occurrence set up on 1st Jan 2000 and still in use now you would need to have a range of ~5000 (and increasing) which would likely be very slow.

Comment: Another suggestion might be having a query for each frequency, UNIONing the results together. So for weekly you can just check the day of week (and I presume the time as well). Monthly the day of the month. Yearly the day of the year. While one offs would use something like my query.

Comment: I have to use it for an "agenda". I need to show only 35(MAX) days for time(range). I'm not interested to use a range of 1000 days

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear. If it were a daily occuring id I presume it could be set up at any time and needs to apply ever after. So if originally set up for 01/01/2000 to occur daily that suggestion would require adding amounts to it until it was within the 35 day range you are interested in. Or am I misunderstanding you and a daily id will only be relevant for up to 35 days after its initial date?